# Inequality with prime numbers

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

I found exercise in my book for number theory that I can't resolve.  How do you show that
$$p_n < e^{1+n}$$
where $p_n$ is $n$-th prime number?

Comment: I think this follows from Bertrand's Postulate...are you allowed to assume that?

Comment: Bertrand's postulate is proofed, so We can use it :) But the best is the easiest proof.

Comment: There are many results about the bounds of the $n$th prime. They perhaps are helpful, chee up :)

Comment: @TheKwiatek666 So you want a proof that does not use Bertrand's Postulate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try induction. For the base case of $n=1$, it is clear that $p_{1}=2<e^{1+1}=e^2$. Now let's suppose for all $k$ where $n \geq k >1$ that our result holds. We know by Bertrand's Postulate that $p_{k+1}<2p_{k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and by induction we know $2p_{k}<2e^{k+1}$. It follows that $$p_{k+1}<2e^{k+1}<(e)e^{k+1}=e^{k+2}$$ We now know our result holds for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This is one of the first exercises in this book. Maybe is it possible to resolve that without Bertrand's Postulate? This theorem is proofed four chapters later.